# How to update Python version running Python in Matlab using pyenv?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, compatibility, pyenv

On MATLAB (MacOS) with:

```
pe = pyenv;
pe.Version
ans =
"2.7"
```

In terminal:

```
python --version
Python 3.8.5
```

How can I update Python in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2020a/matlab/matlab_external/system-and-configuration-requirements.html) states that:

> ...You cannot switch between versions of Python in a single MATLAB session... If you want to change versions, restart MATLAB and then run [`pyenv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pyenv.html) with the new version information.
>
> **Set Python Version on Windows Platform**
> On Windows® platforms, use either:
>
> ```
> pyenv('Version','version')
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> pyenv('Version','executable')
> ```
>
> `ℹ`  **Note:** If you downloaded a Python interpreter, but did not register it in the Windows registry, use:
>
> ```
> pyenv('Version','executable')
> ```
>
> **Set Python Version on Mac and Linux Platforms**
> To set the version, type:
>
> ```
> pyenv('Version','executable')
> ```
>
> where `executable` is the full path to the Python executable file.